# Inheritance and "super" with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, oop, inheritance, super

I have a hard time understanding how to correctly use `inheritance` here and to correctly design my program.

I tried to simplify my code as much as possible.
So I get pandas dataframes, and for each row I will create a XML message for an API endpoint.
I have the following code:

```
class Parse:

    def __init__(self, row):
        self.row = row

    def parse_header(self):
        header = f'''<header>
            <period>{self.row['year_period']}</period>
            <date>{self.row['date_text']}</date>
        </header>'''

        return header


class Prep(Parse):

    def __init__(self, data, file_name):

        super().__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.file_dir = os.path.join('data', 'raw')
        self.file_name = file_name

    def create_line(self):
        self.data['line_xml'] = self.data.apply(lambda x: self.parse_header(x), axis=1)

        return self.data
```

What makes it difficult is that `Parse` operates on each row of the dataframe and gets `scalar` values. While `Prep` operates on the whole dataframe / columns.

So I got stuck at `super().init`, what should I give as argument there, because right now `self.parse_header` in `Prep` does not accept any arguments.

I am open for a completely different design if this is not the way to go.

Comment: It looks like this a "has a" relationship (Prep has Parse rows) not an "is a" relationship (Prep is not a specialization of Parse). It seems like this is not a good candidate for inheritance.

Comment: Yes I can imagine that, but I'm honestly stuck with this design, I tried many other things, but Im just not sure how to incorporate the creating of the header on row level of the dataframes in `Prep`

Comment: I don't know your data but generally you write things to handle many rows. A class instance per row seems to negate the advantages of pandas. You aren't parsing that row, you are turning it to XML. Maybe ditch Parse completely and just have a `Prep.row_to_xml` method that does that fragment. It could be called by `Prep.to_xml()`. In fact, its just one line of code so just put it in the whatever is formatting multiple rows.

Comment: Sometimes OOP is evil. This may be a good case for  a handful of functions that do the work.

Comment: Funny that you mention it. I had a perfectly working code in 5 functions without classes, and all with vectorized numpy/pandas methods. Only the to_xml function I use `apply`, because that seems necessary here. But then one of me senior colleagues told me to make it OOP, without even looking into details, so here I am :) @tdelaney

Comment: Sometimes OOP is good, but its also a cult. Maybe sneak in at night and try an exorcism at his desk? OOP is great if you have generalized functionality that can be applied to inherited specializations. But really most of code is just procedural with a class veneer. I watched a great rant on OOP, saying that if a class has two methods, one of which is `__init__`, you've got a problem. You've got a problem. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: I would be interested to read / watch that one!

Comment: [Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0),
[Is Object-Oriented Programming a Trillion Dollar Disaster?](https://developers.slashdot.org/story/19/07/22/0426201/is-object-oriented-programming-a-trillion-dollar-disaster), [go](https://golang.org/). Thank goodness we haven't veered off into opinion!

Comment: Thanks will share this internally @tdelaney

Comment: You could always point out that in python a function is a first class object so you're always OOP.